# How do I change rotation on this card fan effect dynamically?

Tags: css, sass

I have a css hearthstone-style card hover effect and I was wondering how could I conditionally render this so that when there's fewer cards in the list the rotation amount changes. [image: Full card list] < full card list

[image: singular card] < singular card that I would prefer to be centered like card 5 in the full card list when it's the only card in the list.

https://codepen.io/JavontaeH/pen/wvmyyXK

```
html,
body {
  height: 100% ;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(#333, #111);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards {
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.card {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 -25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  cursor:pointer;
  &:after {
    // uncomment background below to see hit areas
    //background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: -60px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -60px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10
  }
}

.card-face {
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) transform;
  &:after {
    animation: none;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

.card-label {
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.025em;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

$total: 10;
@for $i from 0 through ($total - 1) {
  $hue: ($i / $total) * -360;
  $rotationRange: 50;
  $rotation: ($i - ($total - 1) / 2) / ($total - 2) * $rotationRange;
  $offsetRange: 80;
  $offset: abs(($i - ($total - 1) / 2) / ($total - 2) * $offsetRange);
  .card:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
    .card-face {
      background: linear-gradient(
        -135deg, hsla($hue, 100%, 80%, 1),
        hsla($hue, 90%, 45%, 1)
      );
      box-shadow: 
        -5px 5px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.15),
        inset 0 0 0 2px hsla($hue, 100%, 80%, 0.75)    
      ;
      transform: translateY($offset * 1px) rotate($rotation * 1deg);
      .card-label {
        color: hsla($hue, 100%, 43%, 1);
        text-shadow: -0.025em  0.025em 0 hsla($hue, 100%, 75%, 1);
      }
    }
    &:hover {
      .card-face {
        box-shadow: 
          0 10px 20px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4),
          inset 0 0 0 2px hsla($hue, 100%, 80%, 0.75)    
        ;
        transform: translateY(-100px) rotate(0deg) scale(2);
        transition-duration: 0ms;
        z-index: 5;
        &:after {
          animation: fade 250ms ease-out forwards;
        }
      }
      &:after {
        top: -175px;  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when it will be alone?

Comment: @Nikkkshit for example if you were drawing cards from a deck your hand wouldn't always be full... you can change the html here to reduce the amount of cards in the list. when there's less cards I want to rotation to be treated differently.

Comment: Javascript, I'm guessing. The css here sets up a fixed layout. For the layout to be dynamic based on the number of cards, but still be static css, the css would need to be aware of the total number of items, but css doesn't have that capability. (There are tricks to get around that, but it requires an upper and lower bound and, in this case, would generate an unreasonable amount of css.)